# unable to get page likes although i am admin of both app and page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am preparing a data analysis tool. i am unable to get the likes and reactions on posts of a page (i get a grayed mark on the filed in the graph API explorer) although i am the admin on the test app, and an admin of the page and the documentation clearly states:
""While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app."

i tried both a user token and page token

/MyPageName?fields=id,name,posts{message,comments,likes}
API V3.3

Answer (score 0):

Getting user data for likes and comments requires your app to live and reviewed.

Comment: But the documentation States that while in dev mode, if the user is the admin of both the app and the page he we can get the likes! Is the documentation outdated?!

Comment: Documentation does not refer to public user data which you are trying to access, it refers to your own user data, like you should be able to see your own user name/ID, but not data for other users